# should I use an int/enum or String in my Dart map keys to minimise memory usage?

Tags: javascript, dart

My web app uses (and stores) data in a large [Dart] map. Considering memory and efficiency/performance, should I use an int or a String for the keys, understanding that ints are always 64bit?

As a very simple example:

```
 Map one=new Map();
 one[1]=somedata;
 one[2]=somedata2;
 one[3]=somedata3;

 Map two=new Map();
 two['1']=somedata;
 two['2']=somedata2;
 two['3']=somedata3;

 Map big =new Map();
```

with **big** storing hundreds of **one and two**.

Does one['12345678']=x use the same amount of memory as one[1]=x?

(This would be easy to test if there were a sizeof(one)! )

Should I be bothered at all?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: What do you mean by "hundreds of **one and two**"? Hundreds doesn't sound very big. If you need an ajax call to fetch the data then the size of the key for hundreds of entries should be the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers take less space. Numbers in SMI ("SMall Integer") range (which is signed 31 bit on a 32-bit machine and 63 on a 64-bit machine) just take up one word. Strings, on the other hand, are pointers to an object that represents the string. That is, every string you use lives somewhere on the heap. If you only have few possible strings and you reuse the strings, then the overhead for the strings isn't that high, though.

The integers are also faster for hashcode and equality computations. If it doesn't make your code less readable, you should go for integers. Otherwise, you should evaluate if the performance and memory improvement is really worth the cost of the lost readability (or clarity).

Note: when compiling to JavaScript, things get more complicated. Dart uses JavaScript objects as containers. This means that strings are quite efficient. Normal JavaScript objects are optimized to be used as String maps (although a negative lookup isn't that fast). They are quite efficient with numbers too, but then they don't store the insertion order.
That means, that a linked hashmap (the default Dart Map), cannot just use a JavaScript object as container for numbers. If you want to have an efficient integer map that also works in JavaScript (up to values of 31 bits) you should use `HashMap` from `dart:collection`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one['12345678']=x use the same amount of memory as one[1]=x. Because Dart like Java keeps strings in memory only one time, strings are never duplicated. So I guess you should not bother about keys here.

Comment: Dart doesn't always intern strings. If you get your strings from, say, decoding JSON, you will likely get new strings each time (which is something JSON decoding could be better at, but currently isn't). For canonicalized/interned strings, comparison should be as efficient as integers.